# React/Redux component does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'a try implement shoping cart using React + Redux. I show great with initial data, when i call action it doesn't not work
my reducer

```js
const initalState = {
      loading: false, 
      currentEmployeeId: 1,
      carts: {
        '1': {
          employee: {
            firstName: 'Ha',
            lastName: 'Nguyen',
            id: 1,
          },
    
          services: {
            '1' :
              {id: 1, name: "Fill In Acrylic" },
            '2':
              {
                id: 2, name: "Fill In Gel Color" }
          }
        },
      },
      customer: {
        firstName: "Thuc",
        lastName: 'Vo',  
        id: 2, 
      },
    }
    
    export default function cart(state = initalState, action) {
      switch (action.type) { 
    
        case RECEIVE_DATA:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: false,
          })
    
        case ADD_SERVICE:
          {
            const { currentEmployeeId} = state;
            let service = {
            id: action.service.id,
              name: action.service.name, 
            };    
            return {
              ...state,
              ...state.carts[currentEmployeeId].services[service.id] = service,
              loading: false,
            }
          }   

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Action:

```
export function addService(service){
  return{
    type: ADD_SERVICE,
    service
  }
}
```

and call disptach

```
dispatch(addService({id: 76, name: "4 Designs"}))
```

The service was added to services property, UI doesn't re-render

```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {  
      return {    
        carts: state.cart.carts
      };
    }
```

The cart list:

Employee: Staff name 1
1.Service Name 1
2. Service Name 2
3. Service Name 3

Employee: Staff Name 2
4. Service name 4
5: Service name 5

**Update:**

```
class CartComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const { carts } = this.props;
    return (    

          <div className="div-table-content">
            <table className="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-scroll table-customer-referral">
              <tbody>
                {
                  <Carts carts={carts} />
                }
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>       
    );
  }
}

export default CartComponent;


class CartContainer extends Component {

  render() {    
    return (
      <CartComponent carts={this.props.carts} />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    carts: state.cart.carts
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(CartContainer);
```

Comment: can you provide the code for your component so that we can know what is going on ? If the ui does not re-render maybe you do not use the mapStateToProps function to your component

Comment: function mapStateToProps(state) {  
  return {    
    carts: state.cart.carts
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(CartContainer);

Comment: Please can you add the CartContainer component code as well ?

Comment: CartContainer connect to redux store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is immutable, you shouldn't assign it in the return statement of your service. Instead, create a copy of the state with : `Object.assign({}, obj)` or a deep copy with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

This should works :

```
  const newService = {
    [action.service.id]: { // dynamic object
      id: action.service.id,
      name: action.service.name,
    }
  };

  // deep clone the carts object
  const carts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.carts));
  // assign the newService to the clone
  Object.assign(carts[currentEmployeeId].services, newService);

  return { // add it to new state
    ...state, carts, loading: false,
  };
```

Your data structure make it hard to use, you should avoid to use numbers as key to save tricks like `[action.service.id]`.

Instead try to use something like :

```
const initalState = {
  loading: false,
  currentEmployeeId: 1,
  carts: {
    employee: {
      firstName: 'Ha',
      lastName: 'Nguyen',
      id: 1,
    },
    services: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Fill In Acrylic' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Fill In Gel Color' },
    ],
  },
  customer: {
    firstName: 'Thuc',
    lastName: 'Vo',
    id: 2,
  },
};
```

Since you have the `id` in your object, you can easily retrieve the object your looking for.

Moreover, you should try eslint which is integrated in create-react-app, it will force to clean up your code.

Comment: It does not work. A service don't add to newstate. I should make data structure to better?

Comment: Your right, `Object.assign({}, obj)` didn't create a deep copy like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` and my old code modified the old state. I updated my answer, pls upvote if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: i need copy child property too, using spread operator

```js
export default function cart(state = initalState, action) {
      switch (action.type) { 
    
        case RECEIVE_DATA:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: false,
          })
    
        case ADD_SERVICE:
          {
            const { currentEmployeeId} = state;
            let service = {
            id: action.service.id,
              name: action.service.name, 
            };  
  
           return {
          ...state,
          carts:{
            ...state.carts,
            [currentEmployeeId]:
            {
              ...state.carts[currentEmployeeId],
                services:{
                  ...state.carts[currentEmployeeId].services,
                  [service.id]: service
                }              
            }
          }         
        }

          }   

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```